# need assistance in accessing a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to programming and react, I have a component called App, on App [line 16] I am trying to import a component called Gallery by typing `import Gallery from "/Gallery"` but that is not working, here is a screenshot

[image: Can't import Gallery Component]

Comment: As the error indicates, you need to provide a **relative** path. I assume it's `./Components/Gallery`

Answer (score 4):

Your Gallery file is inside the Components folder, therefore you need to give the exact path to the component, in this case './Components/Gallery'

Comment: thanks for your input, how would I access a folder inside Assets?, I am getting an error for line 5of the same screenshot

Comment: You need to look into learning about directory structure and how the import path will traverse this structure to find the correct path and using relative paths. In the case of Assets folder, you need to go up a parent directorie, out of  'src'. You can use '../' notation to go up directories. From the App.js to Access Assets your relative path will be: './../Assets/{you_asset_name}'

Comment: Yes, I am currently trying to find some good online tutorials about directory structures,do you recommend any good course by any chance?

Comment: Awesome, it is something you will probably learn as you go through general javascript courses/ or in your case some reactjs courses. All this stuff will start to make more sense the deeper you dive, good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

Your path is wrong. It should be `./Components/Gallery` since it's in the same folder as the current component. `/Gallery` goes all the way to the root.

Answer (score 2):

This is not specific to React, it is ES6 module import.

App is not in the same folder as Gallery so you need to specify the path. Try `import Gallery from './Components/Gallery'`

Check http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html for more information.